# Proof of De Morgan's law

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Could someone prove this De'Morgan law: 
$$(\exists x) \neg P(x,y) \iff \neg (\forall x) P(x,y) $$

I am new at this class , never had logic's before so it's pretty hard for me to do this one from scratch.

Comment: Not with propositional calculus ...

Comment: Hope do toy usually go about proving logical equivalences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the forward direction you can reason in the following manner. Left hand side say that there exist $x$, let it be $x_0$, such that $P(x_0,y)=0$. Now what right hand side says is that $P(x,y)$ is not true for all x, which is true because we know at least one $x=x_0$ which makes it false.
You can reason similarly in the reverse direction.

Comment: How do we know that P(Xo,Y)=0 ?

Comment: For forward implication, we assume left hand side to be true and show that right hand side is true. Similarly for reverse implication we assume right hand to be true and show left hand side is true.

Comment: Oh okay i got it, thank you pretty much , now i got an idea how to do this beacuse we were using other thigs to prove that this is logically valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof using a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/). The proof checker does not accept statements with free variables such as $y$ so I replaced it with a name, $a$.

Similar proofs of conversion of quantifiers are available in *[forallx](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf)* Chapter 36 "Derived Rules".

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf